# JQuery and Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - no clues about the real pitfall

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem writing an handler for dynamically generated elements in DOM.

My object is composed with a few attributes and some methods

```
function JMaze(c,r,selector) {
   this.maze = new Array();
   this.content = new Array();
   this.c = c;
   this.r = r;
   this.x = 0;
   this.y = 0;
   this.selector = selector; //need a DOM place to fit with the maze
   this.bookmark = "Home";

   //...other methods...

  this.goTo = function(event){
    console.log("HERE");
    var maze = this.maze;
    var bookmark = this.bookmark;
    var start, destination; 
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) 
        for (j = 0; j < r; j++) 
            if (maze[i][j].id == bookmark)
                start = maze[i][j];
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < r; j++) {
            if (maze[i][j].id == event.data.id)
                destination = maze[i][j];               
        }
    }
    var p = this.findShortestPathAndGo(start,destination);
    this.renderMaze(p);
  };

  this.showMenu = function() {
    var content = this.content;
    var div = "<div class=\'jMenu\'>";
    $.each(content, function(index, value) {        
        div += "<div menuval=\'" + value.id + "\'>" + value.id + "</div>";
    }); 
    div += "</div>";
    $( "body" ).append(div);
    $.each(content, function(index, value) {    
        $("[menuval='" + value.id + "']").on(
            "click", //event
            {id: value.id}, //data
            **this.goTo** //handler         
        );
    }); 

  };
};
```

When I call **showMenu** everything works fine, and the block near the end does what expected binding the click on DOM objects with attribute menuval with the right value.
BUT when i click, and the handler is called, Chrome debug says this

[image]

locating the error in **jquery.min.js:3**.

Actually, it never gets into **goTo** function.

Someone around may know why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go up the stack frames and find the frame that's in your code, to see what jQuery function you're calling. Check the arguments you're passing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer

First, you need to keep a reference to the `JMaze` object if you want to use it inside the callback, like this:

```
var that = this;
```

Then, you need to ensure `JMaze.goTo` has the appropriate context, meaning `this` will be a reference to the `JMaze` object, you can do it by using the `jQuery.proxy` function, like this:

```
$.proxy(that.goTo, that);
```

So, to put it together:

```
this.showMenu = function() {
    var that = this;
    var content = this.content;
    var div = "<div class=\'jMenu\'>";
    $.each(content, function(index, value) {
        div += "<div menuval=\'" + value.id + "\'>" + value.id + "</div>";
    }); 
    div += "</div>";
    $( "body" ).append(div);
    $.each(content, function(index, value) {
        $("[menuval='" + value.id + "']").on(
            "click", //event
            {id: value.id}, //data
            $.proxy(that.goTo, that) //handler
        );
    }); 
};
```

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FnbPp/6/). I added some basic data just to test it.

## Suggestion

I highly suggest you to take advantage of jQuery's way of creating new DOM elements on the fly ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)) and rewrite the entire function like this:

```
this.showMenu = function () {
    var that = this;
    var div = $('<div/>').addClass('jMenu');

    $.each(this.content, function (index, value) {
        $('<div/>')
            .attr('menuval', value.id)
            .text(value.id)
            .appendTo(div)
            .on('click', { id: value.id }, $.proxy(that.goTo, that));
    });

    $('body').append(div);
};
```

Comment: It's actually working! Now i think i got the poi about contexts: just to be sure, so if into goTo i need to call another method i have to save the context again, am i right?
Im thinking about
var p = this.findShortestPathAndGo(start,destination);
this.renderMaze(p);

Comment: The trouble is that JMaze is full of methods calling other methods, goTo calls findShortestPathAndGo, that calls other two method. Maybe i should symplify everything or split everything.

Comment: No, you don't have to. If you call another function from within `goTo` it will retain the same context, the same goes even in case of nested functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `this.goTo` as a value. Binding a method to an object only works when you actually call the function, e.g. `this.goTo()` , not when you just refer to it as a value.

Also, inside `$.each()`, `this` is the current element of the iteration, it's not the `JMaze` object.

Try:

```
var self = this;
$.each(content, function(index, value) {    
    $("[menuval='" + value.id + "']").on(
        "click", //event
        {id: value.id}, //data
        function() {self.goTo();} //handler         
    );
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, i actually missed the **this** bound inside **$.each** !

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes, you can pass a function reference to `.on()`. But if you pass `self.goTo`, it will just be the function, it won't be bound to the `self` object.

Comment: `this.goTo` needs to use `this.c`, `this.r`, etc.

Comment: @Barmar inside goTo i am using this.c etc, but they are undefined at runtime

Comment: It looks like you're just using `c`: `for (i = 0; i < c; i++)`

Comment: Yes, btw if i use
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.maze)); just after var maze = this.maze; i can see it's undefined.
Moreover, I get the error even when i call 
var p = this.findShortestPathAndGo(start,destination);
it says findShortestPathAndGo is undefined, but of course it's not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56704/discussion-between-luigi-and-barmar).